# Bash while loop calling a Python script

Tags: python, bash, while-loop

I would like to call a Python script from within a Bash while loop. However, I do not understand very well how to use appropriately the while loop (and maybe variable) syntax of the Bash. The behaviour I am looking for is that, while a file still contains lines (DNA sequences), I am calling a Python script to extract groups of sequences so that another program (dialign2) can align them. Finally, I add the alignments to a result file. Note: I am not trying to iterate over the file. What should I change in order for the Bash while loop to work? I also want to be sure that the while loop will re-check the changing file.txt on each loop. Here is my attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Call a python script as many times as needed to treat a text file

c=1
while [ `wc -l file.txt` > 0 ] ; # Stop when file.txt has no more lines
do
    echo "Python script called $c times"
    python script.py # Uses file.txt and removes lines from it
    # The Python script also returns a temp.txt file containing DNA sequences
    c=$c + 1
    dialign -f temp.txt # aligns DNA sequences
    cat temp.fa >>results.txt # append DNA alignements to result file
done
```

Thanks!

Comment: You possibly need to be a bit clearer about what isn't working at the moment...

Comment: `wc -l file.txt` will return something like `100 file.txt`, if you really want to use wc you'd need to extract the number. E.g. `wc -l file.txt | cut -f1 -d' '`

Comment: Why not call the Python from a Python script?

Comment: The reason it that I will need to use 2 other programs, dialign2 (aligning DNA sequences) and cat (appending alignment results to a result file). I am not comfortable to call these using Python and bash seemed a natural choice. Plus, I am learning bits of bash programing that I wanted to put into context by shaping a small script together.

Comment: Your code (very bizarre, BTW) gives us little info about what you are actually trying to do. You may paste an example of data (input and output).

Comment: @tokland I think the text description gives a fairly good idea about what I am trying to do. I don't feel you need to see either the insides of my python script nor the data to help me put the bash part together. Indeed, I already have accepted MattH's answer as solving my problem. I certainly make a an effort to post clearer questions in the future. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea why you want to do this.

```
c=1
while [[ -s file.txt ]] ; # Stop when file.txt has no more lines
do
    echo "Python script called $c times"
    python script.py # Uses file.txt and removes lines from it
    c=$(($c + 1))
done
```

Comment: `-s file` is True if the file exists and has a size greater than zero.

Comment: You just have to be careful that the python script doesn't leave any trailing newline or whatnot.

Comment: There's plenty about this question that prompts warnings of caution. I'm struggling to imagine why a python script without arguments would need to be called multiple times by bash.

Comment: Thanks, that totally does the trick for me. The reason I want to do that (suggest another approach if you see a better one) is to recursively align DNA sequences using the program 'dialign2', while choosing which sequences to align with a Python script each time and removing those sequences from the input text file (in fasta format) for another pass. The choosing of the sequences to align is based on a portion of there name, which I feel very comfortable doing in Python. Thanks again!

Comment: I added details in code to show a bit more about what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

try `-gt` to eliminate the shell metacharacter `>`

```
while [ `wc -l  file.txt`  -gt 0 ]
do
    ...
    c=$[c + 1]
done
```

Comment: what exactly is the -gt operator doing?

Comment: or you can use `>` inside `while (( ))` for integer comparisons like this: `while (( $(wc -l < file.txt) > 0 ))` (I learned from **ghostdog74** about the redirection with `wc` which eliminates the filename and only returns the count.)

Comment: you don't need to scan the entire file to know whether it's empty; `-s` will of course work, as will (just for fun) `grep -lv '^ *$' file.txt >/dev/null` which will detect (and stop after) the first non-blank line -- with status 1 for a file with one or more non-empty lines, and status 0 for all other cases (incl. empty/zero-byte files)

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you say you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

c=1
while read line; 
do
    echo "Python script called $c times"
    # $line contains a line of text from file.txt
    python script.py 
    c=$((c + 1))
done < file.txt
```

However, there is no need to use bash, to iterate over the lines in a file. You can do that quite easily without ever leaving python:

```
myfile = open('file.txt', 'r')

for count, line in enumerate(myfile):
    print '%i lines in file' % (count + 1,)
    # the variable "line" contains the line of text from the file.txt 

    # Do your thing here.
```

Comment: UUOC. no need cat with while loop

Comment: Hi, I am not trying to merely iterate over the lines of a file, but to create another temporary file on each pass to be used by another program, until the original file is empty. I added details to the question. Cheers

Comment: @ghostdog74: True. But if you try while read x < file.txt, you get an infinite loop. I've improved my example.

Answer (score 0):

@OP if you want to loop through a file , just use while read loop. Also, you are not using the variables $c as well as the line. Are you passing each line to your Python script? Or you just calling your Python script whenever a line is encountered? (your script going to be slow if you do that)

```
while true
do
    while read -r line
    do
       # if you are taking STDIN in myscript.py, then something must be passed to
       # myscript.py, if not i really don't understand what you are doing.

       echo "$line" | python myscript.py > temp.txt
       dialign -f temp.txt # aligns DNA sequences
       cat temp.txt >>results.txt
    done <"file.txt"
    if [ ! -s "file.txt" ]; break ;fi
done
```

Lastly, you could have done everything in Python. the way to iterate "file.txt" in Python is simply

```
f=open("file.txt"):
for line in f:
    print "do something with line"
    print "or bring what you have in myscript.py here"
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to loop through a file. I added details to the original question.

Comment: yes you are. you are using wc -l on file.txt with while loop, that means you are iterating a file. the only difference is whether you want to use the line variable that is iterated or not.

Comment: I am merely trying to use a characteristic of the file (the fact that it still has information in it) as a criterion for continuing to use the Python script on it. I guess the 'wc' function IS iterating the file. Is this what you mean?

Comment: yes, that's what i mean. because you are checking for count of lines